# running beaglebone image on qemu : libusb error

Tags: qemu, beagleboneblack, angstrom-linux

I'mt trying to run beaglebone image on qemu following this [tutorial](https://wiki.linaro.org/Resources/HowTo/Qemu-beagleboard). im using ubuntu 14.04 and installed qemu as shown in the [tutorial](https://wiki.linaro.org/Resources/HowTo/Qemu-beagleboard)

when ruining the command

```
qemu-system-arm -M beaglexm -drive if=sd,cache=writeback,file=Angstrom-TI-GNOME-image-eglibc-ipk-v2012.01-core-beagleboard-2012.01.11.img -clock unix -serial stdio -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse -usb -device usb-net,netdev=mynet -netdev user,id=mynet
```

I got this error :

```
qemu-system-arm: symbol lookup error: qemu-system-arm: undefined symbol: libusb_get_port_numbers
```

I dont know if it's libusb version issue or what.

Comment: Please tell us what system you're running (debian, ubuntu, freebsd, etc). Also, how did you install qemu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar bug report on https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=711589

I had the same message on my system. To solve it you have, as root, to link in the correct libusb.

```
sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by running (YMMV on where the 'qemu' binaries are located):

ldd /usr/bin/qemu-system-arm

You should get a lot of output indicating what runtime libs Qemu needs and where the system is finding them. The fact that you are getting a 'missing symbol' error means that a shared library is on the system, it just isn't exporting the 'libusb_get_port_numbers' function signature.

If the above is true, then either A) your distro's 'libusb' packages don't export that function (it might have been deprecated) or B) you have some other 3rd party application that installed it's own 'libusb' (MPLABX does this, puts it in /usr/local/lib and symlinks back to /opt/microchip).

Without any more OS info etc, it's hard to help.